# Security issues with cgroup device access in privileged container

Tags: linux, container

I'm currently working on a project where I need to edit a runc configuration to stop allowing for wildcard cgroup device access inside the container, or essentially writing below to devices.allow. This is apparently due to some potential security issues, but I do not understand how this could be exploited by a user inside the container. Is this insecure at all and can it be exploited?

```
 {"allow" : True,
 "type" : "a",
 "access" : "rwm"}
```

Answer (score 0):

A container security issue is not confined to users inside the container.
It's difficult to tell from your description, but what I think you're referring to would be a system user:

> runc's implementation of the linux.resources.devices list was a black-list by default. This means that users who created their own config.json objects and didn't prefix a deny-all rule ({"allow": false, "permissions": "rwm"} or equivalent) were not provided protection by the devices cgroup. This would allow malicious containers (with sufficient privileges) to create arbitrary device inodes (assuming they have CAP_MKNOD) and operate on any device inodes they may have access to (assuming they have regular Unix DAC permissions).

Without full context, your configuration appears insecure because it's breaking deny by default.  It's feasible that it could be exploited, but that depends on the rest of your security model.

**References**
[devices resource list treated as a blacklist by default](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/security/advisories/GHSA-g54h-m393-cpwq)
[cgroup v1 devices](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v1/devices.html)